# Adding Conditional formatting with email validation macro

Tags: excel, vba, validation, email

I originally found this code here [link](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/986125-email-address-validation.html) and it works great. The call function is in cell G56. I am wanting to add another level to it though and have it highlight the merged cell ("B56:F56") green or red based off the validation being true/false.

I was going to try and ask the OP if they had a solution but the site won't let me. 
I've also tried placing conditional formatting on the cells for when they're true/false to change color but that's not working.

This is in module 1

```
Function ValidateEmail(emailAddr As String) As Boolean

    Dim findAt As Long
    Dim findLastDot As Long
    Dim findSpace As Long

'   Default validate is true
    ValidateEmail = True 
                         '<<tried adding then range color selection here no luck 

    findAt = InStr(emailAddr, "@")
    findLastDot = InStrRev(emailAddr, ".")
    findSpace = InStr(emailAddr, " ")

'   Check for characters
    If (findAt = 0) Or (findLastDot = 0) Or (findSpace > 0) Then
        ValidateEmail = False
        Exit Function
    End If

'   Make sure amperand not first space
    If findAt = 1 Then
         ValidateEmail = False
        Exit Function
    End If

'   Make sure the last dot comes at least two spots after the ampersand
    If (findLastDot - 1) <= findAt Then
        ValidateEmail = False
        Exit Function
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: A function called from a worksheet cell is restricted from changing the Excel environment (eg it cannot format ranges/insert values, etc) - it can only return a value to the calling cell.  Conditional formatting should work fine here though.

Comment: so would i have the conditional formatting on cell G or B? or worked into the formula on cell G?

Comment: You can apply the CF to the merged cell but use the value in ColG to drive the formatting (use a formula-based CF rule)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the CF to the merged cell but use the return value from your VBA formula to drive the formatting (using a formula-based CF rule)

[image]

Comment: it says the link cant be found when you click on it

Comment: Re-added.  Can you see *any* images in SO?  Sometimes Imgur is blocked by your workplace...

Comment: Anyway of doing this if its false?

Comment: `=not(validateemail(B2))` and choose a red fill